# Kendo ui MVC datepicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, user-interface, datepicker, kendo-ui

Kendo ui in MVC application automatic add script for datetime values.
I`m use jquery ui datepicker but kendoui add script

```js
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery("#DateRoj").kendoDateTimePicker({
        "format": "dd.MM.yyyy H:mm",
        "min": new Date(1900, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
        "max": new Date(2099, 11, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0),
        "interval": 30
    });
});
```

and i have problem with this editor.
How i can disable auto adding scripts by Kendo?

Comment: try changing ID and name of the date element

Answer (score 0):

The [Kendo UI API documents](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/datepicker) are pretty straight forward on this. If your question actually is about how to initialize it, try **losing the quotes** on the key names ("min", "max" etc.).

A running sample would be:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#DateRoj").kendoDatePicker({
        min: new Date(2011, 0, 1),
        max: new Date(1900, 0, 1),
        format: "yyyy/MM/dd"
    });
});
```

Also note that the `interval` doesn't exist in the [kendo.ui.DatePicker namespace](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/datepicker). So you probably should remove that.

What I can't really make out of your question is if you want to use this mixed with a jQuery datepicker. At least, I'm assuming that's where the interval comes from? If so, that's a combination that will probably not work.

Last, if you really want to "disable automatically adding kendo scripts" you will not be able to use the kendoDatePicker.

Comment: I`m not use kendoDatePicker in this View. I do not know why this script adds.